# Pomodoro app for OSX, that can be downloaded outside the App Store

Tags: gratis, osx, time-management, productivity

In order to be more productive and reduce the risk of RSI, I need an app that reminds me to take regular breaks. I used to use [Be Focused](https://apps.apple.com/it/app/be-focused-focus-timer/id973130201) and I liked it a lot:

- simple yet effective interface
- non-intrusive break notifications (they don't block the whole screen)
- customizable break durations
- the timer can be put on hold
- possibility to minimize to the menu bar
- free(mium) option

Unfortunately, my new company Macbook cannot access the App Store, so I need another app with the above features, **but that can be downloaded outside the App Store**. I'd rather get a free/freemium or Open Source app. However, if you think paid-for alternatives are much better, feel free to propose one.

**EDIT**: system info:

```
Model Name: MacBook Pro
  Model Identifier: MacBookPro16,2
  Processor Name:   Quad-Core Intel Core i7
  Processor Speed:  2,3 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores:    4
  L2 Cache (per Core):  512 KB
  L3 Cache: 8 MB
  Hyper-Threading Technology:   Enabled
  Memory:   32 GB

  System Version:   macOS 11.6.5 (20G527)
  Kernel Version:   Darwin 20.6.0
  Boot Volume:  Macintosh HD
  Boot Mode:    Normal
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [Super Productivity](https://github.com/johannesjo/super-productivity) for quite a while now and totally can recommend it. It can be used like a bare bone pomodoro (just not adding tasks and not finishing the days), or you can dedicate some time into it and use it as a full blown task manager

Comment: Interesting. However, on the Super Productivity [releases page](https://github.com/johannesjo/super-productivity/releases) there are multiple `.dmg` files, and a `mac.zip`. Which is the right one for me? I added my sys info in the question

Comment: also, can you explain (or point to a guide) on how to use it as a bare bones Pomodoro? I opened it but it seems the only thing I can do is to define tasks. How do I define breaks and sessions length, for example?

Comment: @DeltaIV tap three lines in the upper left corner and you'll see settings on the bottom. Go there and find "Productivity Helper", and press "Pomodoro timer". There will be all of the settings for it you might need, and when done just go to the main screen and start it using triangle with timer in the upper right corner